# Using "focal-type" functionality to summarise observations in data.table

Tags: r, loops, matrix, indexing, data.table

I'm working with evenly spaced time series of wind direction observations (in degrees from 1-360) from multiple weather stations.
As part of a quality control routine, I want to create a column that contains the range (maximum difference in wind direction angles) between any two observations that fall within a specified time period (e.g. 3 minutes) centered around the respective row/observation, calculated separately for each station.

For other, non-circular variables (say air temperature), this can be achieved easily and efficiently using rolling functions.
Due to the circular nature of wind direction data, however, I cannot (as far as I know) calculate the range for a vector of more than two observations directly, see for example:

```r
vec <- c(1, 170, 300)
max(vec) - min(vec)
[1] 299 # instead of 169, which would be correct
```

Instead, I need to calculate the pairwise differences in wind directions for all relevant observations and then search for the maximum of these differences.
The difference between two observations x and y can be calculated using the following function:

`diff_x_y <- function(x, y) 180 - abs(abs(y - x) - 180))`

I came up with an approach based on for loops and matrix indexing, where I first filter by station, then calculate the pairwise differences for ALL observations of a given station using the 'outer' function with the 'diff_x_y' function mentioned above, which results in a matrix that I then loop through to find the maximum of the relevant subset for each observation of the original dataset.

```r
# load packages:
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(RcppRoll)

# create small example data set:
dt <- data.table(datetime = rep(as.POSIXct(seq(as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2022-11-17 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")), as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2022-11-17 00:04:30", tz = "UTC")), by = 30), origin = as.Date("1970-01-01 00:00:00"), tz = "UTC"), times = 2),
                 station = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10),
                 wdir = c(50, 60, 50, 55, 70, 10, 65, 10, 50, 100, 70, 10, 50, 150, 55, 55, 60, 50, 55, 70))

# function to calculate wdir ranges for arbitrary window sizes (in minutes):
calc_wdir_range <- function(data, window_sizes_min) {# window sizes in minutes as vector
  
  dt <- copy(data)
  # uniqe station ids to filter data.table:
  stations <- unique(dt$station)
  
  # function to calculate difference between two angles:
  diff_x_y <- function(x,y) 180 - abs(abs(x - y) - 180)
  
  # transform window sizes from minutes to rows:
  window_sizes <- window_sizes_min* 2 + 1
  
  # list to be filled with data.tables for each station:
  max_data <- list()
  
  for (stat in seq_along(stations)) {
    # filter dt by station
    tmp_dt <- dt[station == stations[stat], .(datetime, wdir)]
    # calculate pairwise differences for all observations of current station:
    tmp_mat <- outer(tmp_dt[, wdir], tmp_dt[, wdir], FUN = diff_x_y)
    no_rows <- nrow(tmp_dt)
    # create names for new columns containing ranges:
    range_col_names <- paste0("range_", window_sizes_min, "_min")
    # create data.table with columns for the max ranges:
    max_vals <- data.table(datetime = tmp_dt$datetime,
                           station = stations[stat])
    for(k in seq_along(window_sizes)){

      # create vector that will be filled with maximum differences:
      max_val <- rep(NA_integer_, times = no_rows)
      window_size <- window_sizes[k]
      # starting position (first value that can be calculated):
      start_pos <- ceiling(window_size/2)
      # No. of steps to move left/right and up/down from central cell:
      moving_inds <- start_pos-1
      for(pos in start_pos:(no_rows-start_pos+1)){
        # move through matrix, index relevant parts, calculate maximum and fill max_val vector:
        max_val[pos] <- max(tmp_mat[(pos-moving_inds):(pos+moving_inds), (pos-moving_inds):(pos+moving_inds)], na.rm = T)
      }
      max_vals[, (range_col_names[k]) := max_val]
      }
    max_data[[stat]] <- max_vals
  }
  # merge data to existing data.table and order by station first:
  dt <- merge.data.table(dt, rbindlist(max_data), on = c("station", "datetime"))
  setkeyv(dt, cols = c("station", "datetime"))
  
  return(dt)
}

# execute function for window sizes of 1 and 2 minutes and inspect results:
(dt2 <- calc_wdir_range(data = dt, window_sizes_min = c(1,2)))


               datetime station wdir range_1_min range_2_min
 1: 2022-11-17 00:00:00       A   50          NA          NA
 2: 2022-11-17 00:00:30       A   60          10          NA
 3: 2022-11-17 00:01:00       A   50          10          20
 4: 2022-11-17 00:01:30       A   55          20          60
 5: 2022-11-17 00:02:00       A   70          60          60
 6: 2022-11-17 00:02:30       A   10          60          60
 7: 2022-11-17 00:03:00       A   65          55          60
 8: 2022-11-17 00:03:30       A   10          55          90
 9: 2022-11-17 00:04:00       A   50          90          NA
10: 2022-11-17 00:04:30       A  100          NA          NA
11: 2022-11-17 00:00:00       B   70          NA          NA
12: 2022-11-17 00:00:30       B   10          60          NA
13: 2022-11-17 00:01:00       B   50         140         140
14: 2022-11-17 00:01:30       B  150         100         140
15: 2022-11-17 00:02:00       B   55          95         100
16: 2022-11-17 00:02:30       B   55           5         100
17: 2022-11-17 00:03:00       B   60          10          10
18: 2022-11-17 00:03:30       B   50          10          20
19: 2022-11-17 00:04:00       B   55          20          NA
20: 2022-11-17 00:04:30       B   70          NA          NA
```

I was wondering if there's a more efficient solution based on the data.table package and it's amazing functionality. What I've come up with so far is to create the necessary number of lead and lag values for a given window size as additional columns and calculate the difference between the current observation and all of it's shifted values, as well as the rowwise maximum of all these differences.
If I now use a rolling window to find the maximum for a given time window, I include comparisons that are outside of the relevant time window. I would need to somehow apply a rowwise function that extracts a specified number of surrounding cells and calculates the maximum of that subset, similarly to the matrix approach described above.  Or maybe there is another approach to achieve the desired output that I haven't thought about.
The approach based on matrix indexing substantially increases the computation time of the whole script, which is problematic since the script will be applied to real-time data in an automated way in the future.
Here is what I've come up with so far:

```r
# window size of 1 minute:
size_mins <- 1
wsize <- size_mins*2 +1
size_dist <- wsize - 1
roll_wind <- (wsize-size_dist):(wsize+ size_dist)
size_roll <- length(roll_wind)
inds <- c((-size_dist):-1, c(1:size_dist))
names_cols <- paste0(rep(c("lag", "lead"), each = length(inds)/2), "_", abs(inds))

dt3 <- copy(dt)
# create lead and lagged values:
dt3[, (names_cols) := shift(wdir, n = inds, type = "lead"), by = station]

names_diff_cols <- paste0("diff_", names_cols)
# calculate differences for each observation to the shifted values:
dt3[,(names_diff_cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 180 - abs(abs(x - wdir) - 180)), .SDcols = names_cols, by = station]

# calculate maximum difference of each observation to its shifted values:
dt3[, max_diff := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = names_diff_cols, by = station]

# calculate rolling average on maximum differences (produces wrong results as max_diff is based on too many observations:
dt3[, max_diff_roll_1_min := roll_max(max_diff, n = wsize, na.rm = T, fill = NA), by = station]

setkeyv(dt3, cols = c("station", "datetime"))

## merge with data.table based on matrix indexing and compare results:

(dt_final <- merge(dt2[, .(datetime, station, wdir, range_1_min)], dt3[, .(datetime, station, max_diff_roll_1_min)], on = c("station", "datetime")))

   station            datetime wdir range_1_min max_diff_roll_1_min
 1:       A 2022-11-17 00:00:00   50          NA                  NA
 2:       A 2022-11-17 00:00:30   60          10                  20
 3:       A 2022-11-17 00:01:00   50          10                  45
 4:       A 2022-11-17 00:01:30   55          20                  60
 5:       A 2022-11-17 00:02:00   70          60                  60
 6:       A 2022-11-17 00:02:30   10          60                  60
 7:       A 2022-11-17 00:03:00   65          55                  90
 8:       A 2022-11-17 00:03:30   10          55                  90
 9:       A 2022-11-17 00:04:00   50          90                  90
10:       A 2022-11-17 00:04:30  100          NA                  NA
11:       B 2022-11-17 00:00:00   70          NA                  NA
12:       B 2022-11-17 00:00:30   10          60                 100
13:       B 2022-11-17 00:01:00   50         140                 140
14:       B 2022-11-17 00:01:30  150         100                 140
15:       B 2022-11-17 00:02:00   55          95                 140
16:       B 2022-11-17 00:02:30   55           5                  95
17:       B 2022-11-17 00:03:00   60          10                  95
18:       B 2022-11-17 00:03:30   50          10                  20
19:       B 2022-11-17 00:04:00   55          20                  20
20:       B 2022-11-17 00:04:30   70          NA                  NA
```

I feel like the heavy lifting is already done after computing the differences to the shifted values and it's only a problem of performing the correct rowwise aggregations.
I would be very grateful for any tips and apologize for the long introduction!

To compare possible approaches for performance, here is some simulated data similar to the real data I'm working with, along with the time it takes on my system to calculate the maximum differences using the 'calc_wdir_range' function with realistic window sizes (1, 10, and 60 minutes):

```r
datetime_vec = as.POSIXct(seq(as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2022-11-17 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")), as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2022-11-18 12:00:00", tz = "UTC")), by = 30), origin = as.Date("1970-01-01 00:00:00"), tz = "UTC")

dt_full <- data.table(datetime = rep(datetime_vec, times = 15),
                            station = rep(c(LETTERS[1:15]), each = length(datetime_vec)),
                            wdir = sample(1:360, size = length(datetime_vec)*15, replace = T))

system.time(dt_full2 <- calc_wdir_range(data = dt_full, window_sizes_min = c(1, 10, 60)))

       User      System      elapsed
      10.19        1.28       11.47
```

Comment: Since the time between observations is constant, could you specify the rolling window by number of rows instead of by time?

Comment: Sure, this is what happens inside the function. The initial window size is given in minutes because it's extracted from a spreadsheet with fixed units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a better algorithm for finding the range of the angles:

Sort the angles. Find the maximum difference between the sorted angles and 360 minus the range of the angles. That gives the maximum gap between any two angles. 360 minus that answer is the smallest range of angles that would fit all the angles.

To demonstrate:

```
a <- sample(360, 10)
(s <- sort(a))
#>  [1]  56  58  67 118 214 249 303 328 342 356
```

The maximum gap between adjacent angles is 214 - 118 = 96.

```
max(diff(s), s[1] - s[length(a)] + 360)
#> [1] 96
```

Therefore all the angles are less than 118 or greater than 214, which is a range of 360 - 96 = 264.

```
360 - max(diff(s), s[1] - s[length(a)] + 360)
#> [1] 264
```

As a function:

```
f <- function(a) 360 - max(diff(s <- sort(a)), s[1] - s[length(a)] + 360)
f(a)
#> [1] 264
```

---

### Rolling wind direction ranges

> I'm working with evenly spaced time series of wind direction
> observations

If that's the case, maybe you could specify the window by rows rather than by minutes. This makes the rolling computation much easier.

If the window sizes are not too large, you can add each window as a column in a matrix, then do the column sorting, differences, and maximum for all windows in one shot:

```
library(Rfast)

fRollMaxAngle <- function(a, w) {
  n <- length(a)
  lapply(
    w,
    function(x) {
      c(rep(NA_real_, (x - 1)%/%2), 360 - colMaxs(rbind(diff(s <- colSort(matrix(a[sequence(rep(x, n - x + 1), 1:(n - x + 1))], x))), s[1,] - s[x,] + 360), TRUE), rep(NA_real_, x%/%2))
    }
  )
}
w <- 3:5
dt[,paste("range", w, "rows", sep = "_") := fRollMaxAngle(wdir, w), station][]
#>                datetime station wdir range_3_rows range_4_rows range_5_rows
#>  1: 2022-11-17 00:00:00       A   50           NA           NA           NA
#>  2: 2022-11-17 00:00:30       A   60           10           10           NA
#>  3: 2022-11-17 00:01:00       A   50           10           20           20
#>  4: 2022-11-17 00:01:30       A   55           20           60           60
#>  5: 2022-11-17 00:02:00       A   70           60           60           60
#>  6: 2022-11-17 00:02:30       A   10           60           60           60
#>  7: 2022-11-17 00:03:00       A   65           55           55           60
#>  8: 2022-11-17 00:03:30       A   10           55           90           90
#>  9: 2022-11-17 00:04:00       A   50           90           NA           NA
#> 10: 2022-11-17 00:04:30       A  100           NA           NA           NA
#> 11: 2022-11-17 00:00:00       B   70           NA           NA           NA
#> 12: 2022-11-17 00:00:30       B   10           60          140           NA
#> 13: 2022-11-17 00:01:00       B   50          140          140          140
#> 14: 2022-11-17 00:01:30       B  150          100          100          140
#> 15: 2022-11-17 00:02:00       B   55           95           95          100
#> 16: 2022-11-17 00:02:30       B   55            5           10          100
#> 17: 2022-11-17 00:03:00       B   60           10           10           10
#> 18: 2022-11-17 00:03:30       B   50           10           20           20
#> 19: 2022-11-17 00:04:00       B   55           20           NA           NA
#> 20: 2022-11-17 00:04:30       B   70           NA           NA           NA
```

Comment: First, many thanks for your detailed answer!
There is a problem with your function to find the range of values. An angle between two observations cannot be greater than 180 degrees since in that case you could just go "the other way" around the circle. In your example the greatest angle is 178° (between observations 67 and 249). The way I defined range was probably misleading. I meant the greatest angle between any two observations in the considered time period.

Comment: For two angles, the function I provided will never exceed 180°, but it can exceed 180º for more than two angles, which is what I demonstrated. You should be able to see from the resulting `data.table` that the output is correct.

Comment: You're right, it makes more sense to think about the range as the part of the entire circle that encompasses all observations instead of only considering the maximum between any two observations. Thanks again!